# How to correctly use instance variables in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I often see in code the use of instance variables in different ways, I am not sure how to use them properly in objective-c. For example, in the following code, I declare the property `imagePicker`, which also creates the underlying instance variable `_imagePicker`.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(void)initVariables{


}
```

When do I properly use the following? I have seen all three ways utilized in code, but do not understand the circumstances in which to use them.

```
self._imagePicker =

_imagePicker.property 

imagePicker.property
```

Comment: `self._imagePicker` Is that worked ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think any of the snippets you have listed will work...

```
self._imagePicker //Does not exists, it should be self.imagePicker

_imagePicker.property //There is no property "property" in object of type UIImagePickerController

//And the same error goes for your last example.
```

I'm guessing you have seen it two ways that are common.  `self.imagePicker` or `_imagePicker`.  These two access points do different things and are useful in different circumstances.

`self.imagePicker =` actually calls the `[self setImagePicker:object]` method.  If you don't create this method manually the method will be synthesized for you by the compiler.

`_imagePicker =` just sets the object directly without calling that method.

So where this becomes a problem is if you implement your own `[self setImagePicker:]` method.  Inside that method you would do something like:

```
-(void)setImagePicker:(UIImagePickerController*)controller
{
    self.imagePicker = controller;
}
```

This code is very bad.  Since `self.imagePicker =` gets changed by the compiler to `[self setImagePicker:]` then you are calling that method recursively to no end.  Your program crashes right there (after quite a while of 100% cpu usage and no UI functionality). Instead you should use the instance variable directly when you write the setter method:

```
-(void)setImagePicker:(UIImagePickerController*)controller
{
    _imagePicker = controller;
}
```

I hope this explains a little.

Comment: I know those won't work, I used 'property as an example,' I could have used mediaTypes. Thanks for the  answer, I understand now)

Comment: Those are methods, not functions. And the modern compiler will synthesize property methods without `@synthesize`.

Comment: To avoid the recursive issue, I can simple use '_imagePicker' when setting the variable within the 'setImagePicker' method, correct?

Comment: @Nikita Yes, that is how you would do that correctly.  But if you don't need to do extra code inside that method I would not create it manually, let the compiler do it for you.